# I could'nt use ethernet in windows so i installed Ubuntu14.04 but its same.i ran the commands results are below

Tags: ifconfig

```
tonycarter@tonycarter-Inspiron-3521:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3705 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:544960 (544.9 KB)  TX bytes:544960 (544.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:85:56:0e:d3:f7  
          inet addr:172.16.5.94  Bcast:172.16.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be85:56ff:fe0e:d3f7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:108344 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44922 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:56709064 (56.7 MB)  TX bytes:6393235 (6.3 MB)

tonycarter@tonycarter-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo servic network-interface restart
[sudo] password for tonycarter: 
sudo: servic: command not found
tonycarter@tonycarter-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo service network-interface restart
stop: Unknown parameter: INTERFACE
start: Unknown parameter: INTERFACE
tonycarter@tonycarter-Inspiron-3521:~$
```

Comment: Looks like only your Wireless is detected. What's the result of "lspci | grep network"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ethernet isn't being detected, you could try this command

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

If it doesn't do anything your ethernet controller broke.